# Custom CSS to BootStrap NavBar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding a Bootstrap navigation bar. This is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
```

I have this css which I got online:

```
  .navbar-custom {
    background-color:#229922;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav ul li a {
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #33aa33;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
    background-color:#33aa33;
}
```

The problem I am having is that it is not loading my CSS. I put this css as a seperate stylesheet and linked it to my HTML page, but it still refuses to work.

I found the CSS at http://www.bootply.com/78010

And in his case it works perfectly, so I cannot understand why mine does not.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

**Update**

This is what I have in my  section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custommenu.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update 2**

Image of File Structure:

[image]

Comment: Post the link code inside <head> that you have used.

Comment: Have you insert the bootstrap 3 css in you're page before use you're css ?

Comment: @Manoj I updated my post

Comment: How is your folder structure? Post the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

change you're order of import

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custommenu.css">
```

**Edit**
you're path is not like the other

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: Remove `./`from all the `href=`

Answer (score 1):

You should always include the jQuery script **before** the bootstrap.js script. Bootstrap depends on jQuery, and ordering matters!

So the script tags would be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**

A good hint for mistakes like these is to open your browser's console (for Firefox Developer Edition, it's Ctrl+Shift+K) and check if there are any errors. This particular error should leave a message in the console like "$ is not defined" or similar.